# Best way to use "isa" method?

Tags: perl

What is the "best" way to use "isa()" reliably? In other words, so it works correctly on **any** value, not just an object.

By "best", I mean lack of un-handled corner cases as well as lack of potential performance issues, so this is not a subjective question.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204316/why-shouldnt-i-use-universalisa/204368#204368) mentions two approaches that seem reliable (please note that the old style `UNIVERSAL::isa()` should not be used, with reasons well documented in the answers to that Q):

```
eval { $x->isa("Class") }
#and check $@ in case $x was not an object, in case $x was not an object

use Scalar::Util 'blessed';
blessed $x && $x ->isa($class);
```

The first one uses `eval`, the second uses `B::` (at least for non-XS flavor of Scalar::Util).

The first does not seem to work correctly if `$x` is a scalar containing a class name, as illustrated below, so I'm leaning towards #2 (using `blessed`) unless somoene indicates a good reason not to.

```
$ perl5.8 -e '{use IO::Handle;$x="IO::Handle";
  eval {$is = $x->isa("IO::Handle")}; print "$is:$@\n";}'          
1:
```

**Are there any objective reasons to pick one of these two approaches (or a 3rd one i'm not aware of) such as performance, not handling some special case, etc...?**

Comment: chromatic's blog had a discussion on this quite a few months ago. I don't recall any keywords to google against though. :-/

Comment: So you're saying #1 is wrong because `perl -wle'print "IO::Handle"->isa("IO::Handle");'` evaluates to true?  I don't `eval` is relevant to the example.

Comment: @Ether - correct. I certainly didn't mean to imply that the "bug" is due to using `eval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an update for 2020. Perl v5.32 has [the `isa` operator](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/01/use-the-infix-class-instance-operator/), also known as the class infix operator. It handles the case where the left-hand argument is not an object it returns false instead of blowing up:

```
use v5.32;
if( $something isa 'Animal' ) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that I've run into a couple bugs with the new `isa` operator that weren't fixed until "v5.36.1".  Using it before then can result in errors when mixed with `UNIVERSAL::isa()`: "Can't locate object method "isa" via package "DateTime" at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/DateTime.pm line 581."  Bugs: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18679 and https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/20354

Answer (score 15):

The `Scalar::Util` implementation is categorically better. It avoids the overhead of the `eval {}` which always results in the setting of an additional variable.

```
perl -we'$@=q[foo]; eval {}; print $@'
```

The `Scalar::Util` implementation is easier to read (it doesn't die for a reason that is unknown to the code). If the eval fails too, I believe what happens is you have walk backwards in the tree to the state prior to the eval -- this is how resetting state is achieved. This comes with additional overhead on failure.

### Benchmarks

**Not an object at all**

```
          Rate eval   su
eval  256410/s   -- -88%
su   2222222/s 767%   --
```

**Object passing isa check**

```
          Rate   su eval
su   1030928/s   -- -16%
eval 1234568/s  20%   --
```

**Object failing isa check**

```
         Rate   su eval
su   826446/s   --  -9%
eval 909091/s  10%   --
```

Test code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark;
use Scalar::Util;

package Foo;

Benchmark::cmpthese(
    1_000_000
    , {
        eval => sub{ eval{ $a->isa(__PACKAGE__) } }
        , su => sub { Scalar::Util::blessed $a && $a->isa(__PACKAGE__) }
    }
);

package Bar;

$a = bless {};

Benchmark::cmpthese(
    1_000_000
    , {
        eval => sub{ eval{ $a->isa(__PACKAGE__)} }
        , su => sub { Scalar::Util::blessed $a && $a->isa(__PACKAGE__) }
    }
);

package Baz;

$a = bless {};

Benchmark::cmpthese(
    1_000_000
    , {
        eval => sub{ eval{ $a->isa('duck')} }
        , su => sub { Scalar::Util::blessed $a && $a->isa( 'duck' ) }
    }
);
```

I used This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi, and `Scalar::Util`, `1.21`

Comment: thanks! I am not familiar enough with internal workings of eval so this basically addresses my vague performance concerns with specific details.

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap the safety checks in a scalar and then use the scalar as a method to keep things clean:

```
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

my $isa = sub {blessed $_[0] and $_[0]->isa($_[1])};

my $obj;

if ($obj->$isa('object')) { ... } # returns false instead of throwing an error 

$obj = {};

if ($obj->$isa('object')) { ... } # returns false as well

bless $obj => 'object';

if ($obj->$isa('object')) { say "we got an object" }
```

Note that `$obj->$isa(...)` is just a different spelling of `$isa->($obj, ...)` so no method call actually takes place (which is why it avoids throwing any errors).

And here is some code that will allow you to call `isa` on anything and then inspect the result (inspired by Axeman's answer):

```
{package ISA::Helper;
    use Scalar::Util;
    sub new {
        my ($class, $obj, $type) = @_;
        my $blessed = Scalar::Util::blessed $obj;
        bless {
            type    => $type,
            obj     => $obj,
            blessed => $blessed,
            isa     => $blessed && $obj->isa($type)
        } => $class
    }
    sub blessed         {$_[0]{blessed}}
    sub type            {$_[0]{isa}}
    sub ref     {ref     $_[0]{obj}}
    sub defined {defined $_[0]{obj}}

    use overload fallback => 1,
                 bool     => sub {$_[0]{isa}};
    sub explain {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->type    ? "object is a $$self{type}" :
        $self->blessed ? "object is a $$self{blessed} not a $$self{type}" :
        $self->ref     ? "object is a reference, but is not blessed" :
        $self->defined ? "object is defined, but not a reference"
                       : "object is not defined"
    }
}
my $isa = sub {ISA::Helper->new(@_)};
```

By placing the code reference in a scalar, it can be called on anything without error:

```
my @items = (
    undef,
    5,
    'five',
    \'ref',
    bless( {} => 'Other::Pkg'),
    bless( {} => 'My::Obj'),
);

for (@items) {
    if (my $ok = $_->$isa('My::Obj')) {
        print 'ok: ', $ok->explain, "\n";
    } else {
        print 'error: ', $ok->explain, "\n";
    }
}

print undef->$isa('anything?')->explain, "\n";

my $obj = bless {} => 'Obj';
print $obj->$isa('Obj'), "\n";

my $ref = {};
if (my $reason = $ref->$isa('Object')) {
    say "all is well"
} else {
    given ($reason) {
        when (not $_->defined) {say "not defined"}
        when (not $_->ref)     {say "not a reference"}
        when (not $_->blessed) {say "not a blessed reference"}
        when (not $_->type)    {say "not correct type"}
    }
}
```

this prints:

```
error: object is not defined
error: object is defined, but not a reference
error: object is defined, but not a reference
error: object is a reference, but is not blessed
error: object is a Other::Pkg not a My::Obj
ok: object is a My::Obj
object is not defined
1
not a blessed reference
```

If anyone thinks this is actually useful, let me know, and I will put it up on CPAN.

Comment: Useful. I'd recommend CPAN.

Answer (score 5):

This might sound a little bit harsh to Perl, but neither one of these is ideal. Both cover up the fact that objects are a tack on to Perl. The `blessed` idiom is wordy and contains more than a couple simple pieces.

```
blessed( $object ) && object->isa( 'Class' )
```

I would prefer something more like this:

```
object_isa( $object, 'Class' )
```

There is no logical operation to get wrong, and most of the unfit uses will be weeded out by the compiler. (Quotes not closed, no comma, parens not closed, calling `object_isa` instead...)

It would take undefined scalars, simple scalars (unless they are a classname that *is a* `Class`), unblessed references, and blessed references that do not extend 'Class' and tell you that no, they are not `Class` objects. Unless we want to go the route of [`autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox)-ing everything, we're going to need a *function* that tells us simply.

Perhaps there might be a third parameter for `$how_close`, but there could also be something like this:

```
if ( my $ranking = object_isa( $object, 'Class' )) { 
   ...
}
else { 
   given ( $ranking ) { 
       when ( NOT_TYPE )    { ... }
       when ( NOT_BLESSED ) { ... }
       when ( NOT_REF )     { ... }
       when ( NOT_DEFINED ) { ... }
   }
}
```

About the only way I can see that we could return this many *unique* falses is if `$ranking` was blessed into a class that overloaded the boolean operator to return false unless the function returned the one value indicating an ISA relationship.

However, it could have a few members: `EXACTLY`, `INHERITS`, `IMPLEMENTS`, `AGGREGATES` or even `MOCKS`

I get tired of typing this too:

```
$object->can( 'DOES' ) && $object->DOES( 'role' )
```

because I try to implement the future-facing DOES in lesser perls (on the idea that people might frown on my polluting `UNIVERSAL`) on them.

Comment: All of these points are near moot with `Moose` which provides a typing system that at the very least will keep non-objects out for you. (though all of these points are valid under the hood).

Comment: Its 2015 now, wheres the type hinting!?!